# adding pictures into scroll viewer

Tags: scroll, viewer

how can i add pictures into scroll viewer in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ([ScrollViewer doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28VS.95%29.aspx)):

```
<ScrollViewer Height="200" Width="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.Left="340">
     <Image src="myImage.jpg" Width="50" Height="50" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

But you might also want to check out the [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel%28VS.95%29.aspx) control.